# Bot Framework (.Net) - Send additional parameters with button using PromptDialog.Choice()

Tags: c#, .net, botframework

I'm trying to learn Bot Framework using .Net and I have an application which displays buttons and based on the option selected, display more buttons or a list. What I want is, to send a hidden ID/parameter with the button so that when user clicks on the button, I can access the hidden parameter. I'm not using cards for this. I just want to display the buttons. Can anyone help me with this? I know this can be a very basic question but I couldn't find how to this without Cards.

Comment: What channel are u using?

Comment: I'm just using the Channel Emulator

Comment: How you are creating/sending the buttons if you are not using cards?

Comment: By using PromptDialog.Choice()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `PromptDialog.Choice` behind the scenes creates a `HeroCard` with multiple buttons (which are basically the `PromptOptions` passed, see [the code](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/PromptDialog.cs#L247))

One way to pass a hidden parameter would be specifying the ActionType `PostBack` to your button and fill the `Value` property with the hidden parameter. `PostBack` is the way to go here since the message will be posted to the bot but client applications will not display this message (however, please note that not all the channels support the postBack action type). See [this](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/attachments.html) for more information

Now, since you are using `PromptDialog.Choice` you will have to override things in order to be able to specify the `PostBack` action type, since by default, the buttons created with the Choice are using `ImBack` (per [this code](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/PromptDialog.cs#L714))

You will have to put together a custom [PromptStyler](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/PromptDialog.cs#L178), override the `Apply<T>` method and add your logic to change the action type and set the buttons in the way you want based on the [PromptStyle](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/PromptDialog.cs#L49) used and pass that custom styler to the `PromptDialog.Choice`.

By default the [PromptDialog.Choice](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/PromptDialog.cs#L346) uses PromptStyle.Auto.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clear explanation. I could learn a lot I didn't know. I tried to do as you have said above. But I cannot understand how to pass values to the custom styler, specially the options (`IReadOnlyList<T>`). It would be really helpful if you can explain that a bit more. But otherwise, I'll try a bit more.

Comment: You can just use an IList<T> and the call .ToList().AsReadOnly()); to convert it to readonly one.